# How to extract contour of a microscopic image and get x,y coordinates of the contour/edge line?

Tags: r, edge-detection

From the tissue microscopic image, I want to extract its contour (edges outlining the tissue shape) and the coordinates of the contour line using R programming language. I tried using contour function. Not sure what is the best way to get the tissue edges/contour from the image and x,y coordinates of the contour line. Ideally want to have coordinates of equidistant-banded contours of the image converging at centroid of its shape to be able to quantify objects/cells of interest within different contour-bands.

Comment: Use the code that I wrote on a piece of paper.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.